# Search using Tags in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-relations

I'm very new to Laravel and

Trying to make a search system by Tags, like I have a `products` table and each products have multiple tags in the `product_tags` table. `product_tags` table has two column `product_id` and `product_tag`

```php
        $search = $req->get('search'); // Input from user 
        
        $products = Product::with(['images', 'tags'])
        ->where('id', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('product_name', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('product_price', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%')
        ->get();

        dd($products);
```

Product Modal

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductTag::class, 'product_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to be able to search on the Product or Tag? what is the name of the field on 'tags' you want to search on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
Product::with(['images', 'tags'])
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('id', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('product_name', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('product_price', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->orWhereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('product_tag', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->get();
```

- [Queries: Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping)
- [Eloquent Relationships: Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)